# WordPress unresponsive after calling wp_update_comment()

Tags: comments, database

In the admin panel's "Edit Comment" page, for some reason after I click "Update" the Edit page goes into infinite loop/loading (the spinner icon in the Google Chrome tab never stops spinning). My computer goes into "deep think" for 10-20 minutes, even after I close WordPress, the web browser, and my IDE (I'm working locally on Microsoft WebMatrix 3).

Calling `wp_update_comment()` seems to be the problem, because when I remove it everything works fine. When I check the database I can see that the 'comment_type' column does get updated though, but my computer still goes into a deep think consuming resources and the Edit page goes into infinite loading.

```
function update_product_comment($comment_ID) {
    $commentarr = [];
    $commentarr['comment_ID'] = $comment_ID;
    $commentarr['comment_type'] = 'test';

    //wp_die(var_dump($commentarr['comment_type'])); <-- COMMENT_TYPE = 'TEST', SO FAR SO GOOD!
    wp_update_comment($commentarr); // <--- THE CULPRIT
}
add_action('edit_comment', 'update_product_comment');
```

I don't know what could be causing wp_update_comment() to do this, I have no plugins installed and a basically fresh WordPress install, default wordpress theme, and no custom code. But the same problem applies no matter what theme I use. Maybe it's WebMatrix I don't know, can someone test the code and tell me if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_update_comment` triggers the `edit_comment` action ([source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L1911)), you're creating an infinite loop.

Comment: THANKS! It's been driving me nuts, no wonder! Hmm... I'm making a comment_type field in the comment edit page. I guess I'll need a new idea to edit the comment_type field...

Comment: A static counter to terminate the loop after 1 go does the trick.

Comment: Instead of implementing a counter, just remove the action at the beginning of the callback to avoid the infinite loop, see my complementary answer for details. @Blastercloud

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the action hook at the beginning of your callback function to avoid the infinite loop - for this you can add:

```
// avoid infinite loop
remove_action( 'edit_comment', 'update_product_comment' );
```

Could be alternatively done like this:

```
// avoid infinite loop
remove_action( 'edit_comment', __FUNCTION__ );
```

Another variation would be:

```
// avoid infinite loop
remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );
```

Just to note that too, only one of above variants is needed.

Comment: My pleasure. The approach works on any hook where you call the the function containing the hook itself, I guess most prominently you'll see this on `pre_get_posts` callbacks where a `WP_Query` is done to get post IDs. @Blastercloud